# Why is enp#s# in stead of eth# ? Whats the meaning of enp#s#?

Tags: server, 15.04

I migrate from Ubuntu Server 14 to Ubuntu Server 16 I now I have problems because I'm not undertand that.

I hope that somebody can answer me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

These interface names are a new standard aimed at providing consistent (and persistent) names of network devices between different boots and Linux installs. There's a good amount of information and rationale here:

https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/

There's also the technical detail of the naming scheme here:

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/udev/udev-builtin-net_id.c#L20

In short, for your case, the `enpXsY` signifies that it's a pci device (from the `p`), on pci bus `X`, in slot `Y`.

Comment: FWIW the first link above references the second link as the canonical source, but the second link has been edited and the comment with the information has been removed; which issue I've raised on a relevant [github](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/12518) pull.

Comment: For those interested in the logic used to name the interfaces, see `man  systemd.net-naming-scheme` (available in Debian 11+ and, I imagine, Ubuntu 20.04+). Online version: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.net-naming-scheme.html