# How to raise failed network interfaces after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, server, dhclient

I am running a remote server a VPS, all was well,

Upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 and immediately my ssh (putty) stopped allowing me access, it just can't find server, cannot ping... it says

> network unreachable

Checked all firewalls and all exactly same as before,

All firewalls open on correct ports, all software runs correctly on reboot, its all working except I cannot connect to server by any means, I cannot SSH,

When running `service networking status` I get the following error report,

[image: networking failure error report]

It is failing to raise networking services and so I cannot access server, it also lists `dhclient` failure,

My Hosting provider provides a terminal interface so I can run commands luckily,

Please help as I have tried ALL articles on net for this including here and no luck, I now have a server which is working fine except neither I or anyone else can ever contact it,

The contents of my `/etc/network/interfaces` file are correct,

```
Loopback interface
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback

Primary Network Interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

please advise as I am not willing to start from scratch with server and don't know why Ubuntu has not fixed this ongoing bug which many people have reported,

Hope you can help?

Comment: Hi,

I ran `ifconfig` results below, then changed `/etc/network/interfaces` file, firstly to `docker0` then to `veth1367b5d` to try raising them,

and ran `ifup` and `ifdown` exactly as you suggested for each one in turn to test them:

![Test results and error message](http://imgur.com/a/ISpDC)

docker is a container running for my discourse forum, and two other Ethernet listed, I tried docker and then one of ethernets but neither produced anything but errors and would not raised network services,

any help would be appreciated

thank you

Answer (score 4):

In 16.04, because of persistent naming, your interface is probably no longer eth0. Check:

```
ifconfig
```

For example, my ethernet interface is now `enp0s25`. Correct your `/etc/network/interfaces` file as needed and then:

```
sudo ifdown enp0s25 && sudo ifup enp0s25
```

Of course, substitue your interface name as needed.

[Why is enp#s# in stead of eth# ? Whats the meaning of enp#s#?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760196/why-is-enps-in-stead-of-eth-whats-the-meaning-of-enps/760243#760243)

Comment: chili, +1, but i think it's time to start telling people to use `ip` as a must :)

Comment: @heemayl Old dogs and new tricks, etc.!

Comment: Thank you will report back, appreciate you taking time to help!

Comment: I have added result of following the suggested steps above, still no luck getting it working, won't raise network service...

Comment: Hi, I ran `ifconfig` results below, then changed `/etc/network/interfaces` file, firstly to `docker0` then to `veth1367b5d` to try raising them, 


and ran `ifup` and `ifdown` exactly as you suggested for each one in turn to test them: 


[Results of your instructions](http://imgur.com/a/ISpDC) 


docker is a container running for my discourse forum, and two other Ethernet listed, I tried `docker0` and then one of ethernets but neither produced anything but errors (see image above) and would not raise network services, 

any help would be appreciated thank you

Comment: I have also found the following `/run/network/ifstate` has deleted any mention of Ethernet ,

[problems with ifstate](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50602/cant-ifdown-eth0-main-interface)

On checking this file only `lo=lo` is in it, suspect that once I identify what Ethernet I should have running will go in this file eg. `enp#s#` etc

Comment: I have now run `ip addr` command and it shows that `eth0` is present with an ipv6 address but not UP, so question is how to I get `/etc/network/interfaces` to recognize `eth0` and how do I raise it to state UP successfully?

[result of ip addr](http://imgur.com/a/NpH2k)

Comment: I am very sorry. I do not know anything at all about Docker.

Comment: thanks its not docker its saying cannot raise eth0

Comment: If an Ubuntu forum can't solve something that lots of people seem to be having problems with (a systemic problem with Ubuntu) there is no chance for the average user to be able to use Ubuntu, I think I will have to go back to Centos as Ubuntu has trashed my server

Comment: see link 

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=cannot+raise+eth0+ubuntu+16+networking+service&ie=&oe=

will raise it as formal bug on SO and Git