# eth0 interface accidentally renamed; now how to fix it

Tags: ifconfig, static-ip

****Raspberry Pi 3. Ubuntu Mate 16.04.****

I was trying to configure a static IP address for the eth0 interface. I followed this tutorial:
https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-basics-set-a-static-ip-on-ubuntu

In the end I get :

```
foo@bar:~$ ifconfig eth0
eth0: error fetching interface information: Device not found
foo@bar:~$ ifconfig enxc914jv7847d6
enxc914jv7847d6 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c3:13:ac:81:34:e4  
      inet addr:192.168.2.142  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: aa80::f751:32e3:ced5:ca78/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:12311 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:9972 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:9090476 (9.0 MB)  TX bytes:1207456 (1.2 MB)
```

Evidently the name of the eth0 interface has been changed to some gawdawful alphanumeric string. I prefer if the ethernet interface was named eth0. Why has this happened? More importantly, how to rectify it?

Comment: This is not accidental. This is by design in 16.04. Check this solution http://askubuntu.com/questions/814320/how-to-raise-failed-network-interfaces-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04/814322#814322

Comment: or Check this one [How to rename network interface in 15.10](http://askubuntu.com/q/689501/295286)

Comment: Have you tried reverting the changes you were following in the tutorial ? Also, try following the link Anwar provided and rename the interface to whatever suits you

Comment: I did revert the changes I made in  `/etc/network/interfaces` but the interface still has that long, seemingly random name.  I am looking at the answer in [How to rename network interface in 15.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/689501/how-to-rename-network-interface-in-15-10) right now. Hopefully I can use that to fix my system.

Comment: I created a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-rename-network.rules` with the contents `SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff", NAME="eth0"`. In other words I did exactly what the answer by richvdh in [How to rename network interface in 15.10?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/689501/how-to-rename-network-interface-in-15-10). After I rebooted the computer, I ran `ifconfig` but still the ethernet interface is listed as enxc914jv7847d6.

Comment: You replaced the `ff:ff:...` with the address of your network card from `ifconfig` right?  If you did not then you need to do that and reboot again.