# ifconfig wlan0 down wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device

Tags: networking, wireless

I am using Ubuntu 16.08 from and am quite new to using the terminal.

When trying to run the following command:

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
```

I get:

```
wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Please clarify your Ubuntu version. It can't be 16.08, I guess you mean 16.04.

Answer (score 4):

In 16.04, because of persistent naming, your interface is probably no longer wlan0. Check:

```
ifconfig
```

For example, my wireless interface is now wlp3s0.

Please try the interface you found:

```
sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 down
```

...or whatever interface you found.

[Why is enp#s# in stead of eth# ? Whats the meaning of enp#s#?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760196/why-is-enps-in-stead-of-eth-whats-the-meaning-of-enps/760243#760243)